# Where are the artifacts in release management 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, release-management, ms-release-management

Is it possible to link the artifacts of a build to a release with release management 2013? There is plenty of documentation for 2015 but cant find anything for 2013.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. At the release template level, you choose what build definition from TFS you'd like to deploy.

Then, in the release workflow, you define a **Component** that specifies an installation action.

Comment: Many thanks. Defining a component and then adding it to the release template is the right answer!!